# Which is currently further from their landing site: Ingenuity or Perseverance? How far away are they from each now?

Tags: mars, rovers, perseverance, ingenuity, helicopter

Ingenuity has flown seven times now and I'm not certain but I think for at least one of the flights it traveled some distance and landed in a new site.

Perseverance has done some traveling as well.

**Question:**

1. Which is currently further from their landing site: Ingenuity or Perseverance?
2. How far away are they from each other now?

There's going to be a range limit for their ZigBee link, so either Ingenuity will have to
keep up with Perseverance or Ingenuity will eventually left on is own *incommunicado* unless there's another radio out there that can be configured to speak ZigBee at 900 MHz.

Related and potentially helpful information:

- [Can anything at Mars speak 900 MHz ZigBee besides Ingenuity helicopter and Perseverance rover?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/50448/12102) " Each radio emits approximately 0.75 W power at 900 MHz with the board consuming up to 3 W supply power when transmitting and approximately 0.15 W while receiving. The link is designed to relay data at over-the-air rates of 20 kbps or 250 kbps **over distances of up to 1000 m.**"
- [How long could the Mars helicopter Ingenuity keep up with the Perseverance rover if it wanted to?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/45672/12102)
- [How Ingenuity ensures it does not fly away from the range of connection from Perseverance?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/52028/12102)
- [In their first 100 sols which NASA Mars rover drove the furthest and which one the least?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/52485/12102)
- [Could Ingenuity stay warmer at night by landing on (or near) Perseverance's RTG?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/45673/12102)
- [At the end of the test campaign, could Ingenuity be programmed to fly fully autonomously to the planned sample cache depot location?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/51675/12102)
- [Will Curiosity and the Mars 2020 rover be able to communicate with each other via a Mars orbiter?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/39991/12102)
- [Does the Ingenuity helicopter on Mars have a radio call sign?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/51177/12102)
- [Is it possible to make an Internet of Things device that works locally on Mars?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/9589/12102)

Comment: I have a feeling the answer to this might change weekly as long as Ingenuity works.

Comment: @BonanKogoj this question has a posting date and it can be answered now. There are plenty of questions here that are in a similar situation, it is generally understood that when "currently" is written it refers to the time of writing.

Comment: A man takes a dog on a leash for a walk. Who is farther from home, the man or the dog? Sure you can say, for any specific moment of time, but does it matter?

Comment: @SF. not to the dog :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NASA has a webpage with an [interactive map](https://mars.nasa.gov/mars2020/mission/where-is-the-rover/) of the rover and helicopter.  As of today,

1. the helicopter is slightly farther (straight-line distance) from the landing site than the rover.
2. the rover and helicopter are about 400 m apart.

[image: Ingenuity and Perseverance]

Of course, the answers will change as the mission progresses.

Comment: I'm not sure why, but the helicopter is now back, much closer to the landing site again, but it doesn't make sense to continue updating the answer. Thanks for finding the website!